# How to return the replicated data instead of boolean in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to `replicate()` eloquent data in laravel, and also return the replicated data instead of bool() data.

**When I do this**

```
$transaction = Transaction::find(1);

$transaction2 = $transaction->replicate()->fill(['status' => 1]);

$transaction2 = $transaction2->save();

return $transaction2;
```

This code returns `true`. How can I return the replicated data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result is happening because you are setting the `$transaction2` to the `save()` result just before your return here `$transaction2 = $transaction2->save();`.

This will override `$transaction2` with the value of `->save()`, which returns true or false whether it successfully saved or not.

Change your code like this, and it will do as you intend.

```
$transaction = Transaction::find(1);

$transaction2 = $transaction->replicate()->fill(['status' => 1]);

$transaction2->save();

return $transaction2;
```

Comment: Any explanation?

Comment: That's perfect :) Didn't noticed this one.